# I won't load mutliple view in controller

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

I'm trying to load multiple view in controller.

It's easy and simple but it seems not working properly.

```
public function index()
{
    $this->_head();  
    $this->load->view('navigation_panel');
    $this->load->view('login'); 
    $this->_footer();
}
```

login page is shown, but this page's only shown w/o navigation_panel.
Event it's not affected by css.

When navigation_panel is only shown with commenting login, it's shown properly with affecting by css.

I don't know why this happen. If anyone knows this symptom, please tell me how to solve it.

Comment: debug it with firebug or developers tool, this is the problem of your HTML not codeigniter or php

Comment: try commenting the `navigation_panel`, if the login form shows up.. then you have a html/css problem else file extension or the file doesn't exist

Comment: I found html problem in login view. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try switching it:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->_head();  
    $this->load->view('login'); 
    $this->load->view('navigation_panel');
    $this->_footer();
}
```

Comment: I tried as you suggested. Login is only shown. Html in Login View can be a problem. I'll debug it. Thanks a lot.